# Parsing a JSON results from influxdb HTTP requests

Tags: json, shell, parsing

I am querying `InfluxDB` using `curl` requests and I got a result that looks like:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "series": [
                {
                    "name": "memory_usage",
                    "columns": [
                        "time",
                        "max"
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        [
                            "2017-07-24T10:43:37.844581595Z",
                            872898560
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to extract automatically the last value (in this example it is `872898560`).

Comment: Can you download and install `jq` on your machine. It is the standard syntax aware JSON parser available

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). If `data.json` contains the sample data then the command

```
$ jq -M '.results[].series[].values[][-1]' data.json
```

produces

```
872898560
```